# Dygraph: How to hide x,y value in legend?

Tags: javascript, legend, dygraphs

While generating a track with the help of dygraph library, I have set the legend: always (this display the legend with series name present on that particular track even without mouseover). But when I move to certain graph, the legend changes and shows the value of each series at that particular mouse pointer. I don't want the legend to change and it should just show the series name and not the values. I am using javascript to implement my app. Any way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

One trick that might be good enough is to supply a custom `valueFormatter` function for each axis which simply returns an empty string:

```
axes: {x: {valueFormatter: function (x) {return ''}},
   y: {valueFormatter: function (y) {return ''}},
   y2: {valueFormatter: function (y2) {return ''}}
}
```

This prevents the values from being shown, but still switches between line samples and ':' characters depending on the position of the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's no easy way to do this. Your best bets are to either generate the legend yourself using dygraphs' API or to throw a transparent div over your chart which captures all the mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Well! it might be not a good way but I have found an alternative to do it. Declared a new boolean  variable in dygraph.js which checks whether user wish to see x-y values on legend. Using this variable in function generateLegendHTML (defined in legend.js), i have made the control to always go in the first if loop. This makes the dygraph to always show static legend.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following -

**Step 0** - Add a few necessary options and tags -

```
labelsDiv: document.getElementById("labels"),// in the dygraph options

<div id="labels"></div> <!-- Add this somewhere in your HTML-->
```

**Step 1** - Declare a variable -

```
var defaultLabelHTML = undefined;
```

**Step 2** - Use drawCallback option -

```
drawCallback: function(dygraph, is_initial){
if (is_initial)
{
defaultLabelHTML = document.getElementById("labels").innerHTML;
}
},
```

**Step 3** - Use highlightCallback option -

```
function(e, x, pts, row) 
{
document.getElementById("labels").innerHTML = defaultLabelHTML;
}
```